# Ongkir+Subtotal Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have an invoice form. Everything works but I have one problem in text input `id='ongkir'`. If I input a value on text input *ongkir* the text input *grandtotal* must be *subtotal+ongkir*. But it doesn't work.

Check this code (auto.js):

```
$(document).on('change keyup blur', '#ongkir', function () {
    calculateTotal();
});

//total price calculation 
function calculateTotal() {
    subTotal = 0; total = 0;
    $('.totalLinePrice').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != '') subTotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#subTotal').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
    ongkir = $('#ongkir').val();
    if (ongkir != '') {
        ongkir = $('#ongkir').val();
        total = subTotal + ongkir;
        $('#grandtotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
    }
    else {
        total = subTotal;
    }
    $('#grandtotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
    calculateAmountDue();
}
```

And this is file transaksi.php:

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subtotal" class="col-sm-7 text-right control-label"><b class="pull-right">Subtotal: </b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Rp</span>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="subTotal" placeholder="Subtotal"
                           onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ongkir" class="col-sm-7 control-label"><b class="pull-right">Ongkir: </b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Rp</span>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ongkir" id="ongkir" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="grandtotal" class="col-sm-7 control-label"><b class="pull-right">Grand Total: </b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Rp</span>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="grandtotal" placeholder="Total" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="bayar" class="col-sm-7 control-label"><b class="pull-right">Bayar: </b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Rp</span>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="bayar" placeholder="Jumlah Bayar" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subtotal" class="col-sm-7 control-label"><b class="pull-right">Tanggal Bayar: </b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tanggal Bayar" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure if this is the issue, but you do have a "<td></td>" wrapped around your field that is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? If not there's not much else I can see wrong here with what's given (other than that `<td>`)..

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var subTotal = 0,
        total = 0;
    $('.totalLinePrice').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') subTotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#subTotal').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
    var ongkir = $('#ongkir').val();
    if (ongkir != '') {
        total = subTotal + parseFloat(ongkir);
        $('#grandtotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
    } else {
        total = subTotal;
    }
    $('#grandtotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
    calculateAmountDue();
}
```

If that don't work I'd check what's going on in "calculateAmountDue()".